# How do I read in and store variables from another file

Tags: mips, qtspim

For example if the file I am trying to read has:

sum: .word 0

How would I read the value for sum and store it into another files variable?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about accessing symbols defined in another source file when using QtSpim. Just load all the source files, and then press the Run button.

An example:

**foo.s**

```
.globl main
.text

main:
    # Print sum
    lw $a0, sum
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    # Exit
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

**bar.s**

```
.data
sum: .word 123
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense